# Caption inside of a minipage

Tags: minipage

I'm looking to include my a figure title (caption) inside of a footnote below the figure rather than above. I commonly use the minipage command, thought including the caption below destroys my alignment. I've included my code below:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
%{\caption*{Historical Output and Welfare Multipliers\label{figure:historical_mult}}}
%\caption{HISTORICAL OUTPUT AND WELFARE MULTIPLIERS\label{figure:historical_mult}}
\vspace{-5mm}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[height=4in,width=6in]{multiplier_graph.pdf}
\end{center}
\vspace{-15mm}
\hfill\begin{minipage}[t]{140mm}
\captionof{figure}{Historical output and welfare multipliers.\label{figure:historical_mult}}

{Big long footnote text.}

\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's not clear to me is whether you want a footnote *and* a caption, or just a caption. In the first case, do you want the caption above or below the footnote?

Comment: Hi @Bernard, I would like both the caption and the footnote to be in one solid block below my figure. Something like...

Figure 1.1 Historical Simulation. In the above figure I show the... etc.

Comment: What sort of alignment were you hoping for?  I take it you want the caption written on top of the image.  Do you want "Figure" even with the left side of the minipage?

Comment: I'd like the minipage, including my footnote and a caption which labels my figure for my table of contents, to be fully aligned with the margins on my figure. A minipage environment would normally expand and contract my text in a way that sharp right and left margins are preserved. I'd like the same thing, only now to include the \caption command for my table of contents. Thanks!

Comment: Interestingly, I could not get \captionsetup to increase the width beyond a certain limit nor find anything in the manual about this.

Answer (score 1):

With the threeparttablex, you can have something that looks like what you want, if I understand well: you can have the caption under the figure, then the notes of the same width as the table. For that, one needs to use the `measuredfigure` environment. As there seems to be a bug with labels in the `measuredfigure` environment, I had to define a `\fakecaption` command to make the `\ label` work. Here is the code:

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{lmodern}

    \usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
    \usepackage{caption, threeparttablex, float}%
    \captionsetup{position = below, labelfont = bf, textfont = it}
    \DeclareCaptionFormat{empty}{\relax}
    \newcommand*\fakecaption{\addtocounter{figure}{-1}\captionsetup{format=empty, skip=0pt}\caption{}}
    \usepackage{cleveref}

    \begin{document}

    Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.

    \begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{measuredfigure}
    \includegraphics[height=3in,width=4in]{multiplier_graph.pdf}
      \caption{Historical output and welfare multipliers.}
     \bigskip
    \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]%
    \item\hskip-\labelsep A very long footnote text. A very long footnote text. A very long footnote text. A very long footnote text.
    \end{tablenotes}
    \end{measuredfigure}
    \fakecaption\label{figure:historical_mult}
    \end{figure}

    \noindent As we can see from \cref{figure:historical_mult}, …

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works great for the figure and footnote, but it seems to clear my labels. I run the file several times acknowledging that it requires multiple runs to save and then print the \ref{} commands, but no luck. Sorry for the trouble!

Comment: @Jonathan: I have a workaround for the label problem, through a `\fakecaption` command, that prints nothing and takes no vertical space but allows a label. See my updated answer.

Comment: A problem with `\fakecaption` is that that both it and the real caption writes entries in the list of figures. I got the following from another question in this site: `\newcommand{\stoptocentries}{\renewcommand{\addcontentsline}[3]{}}
\newcommand{\starttocentries}{\let\addcontentsline\oldaddcontentsline}`. This redifines `\addtocontentsline` in the `\caption` command to do nothing. Surrounding the definition of `\fakecaption` with `\stoptocentries` and `\starttocentries` solves the problem with double LOF entries.

Answer (score 0):

When all else fails, you can always write your own caption.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newif\iffigure
\newif\iftable

\newcommand{\widecaptionof}[2]% #1=figure/table, #2=text
{\refstepcounter{#1}%
\begingroup% trying not to load other packages
\def\a{#1}%
\def\b{figure}%
\ifx\a\b\global\figuretrue\else\global\figurefalse\fi%
\def\b{table}%
\ifx\a\b\global\tabletrue\else\global\tablefalse\fi%
\endgroup%
\iffigure%
  \addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{#2}%
  \textbf{Figure \thefigure: }{#2}%
\fi%
\iftable%
  \addcontentsline{lot}{table}{#2}%
  \textbf{Table \thetable: }{#2}%
\fi%
\par\medskip}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\bigskip
See \ref{figure:historical_mult} for details.

\begin{figure}[H]
%{\caption*{Historical Output and Welfare Multipliers\label{figure:historical_mult}}}
%\caption{HISTORICAL OUTPUT AND WELFARE MULTIPLIERS\label{figure:historical_mult}}
%\vspace{-5mm}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[height=4in,width=6in]{example-image}
\end{center}
%\vspace{-15mm}
\hfil\begin{minipage}{140mm}
\widecaptionof{figure}{Historical output and welfare multipliers.}
\label{figure:historical_mult}
Big long footnote text.
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: custom cpation]